# Terminal size at startup?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a terminal launch at startup that displays a clock. 
accomplished with

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --command /home/noah/bin/clock
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_NG]=Terminal
Name=Terminal
Comment[en_NG]=Start Terminal On Startup
Comment=Start Terminal On Startup
```

saved in `/.config/autostart`
How would i tell that terminal to launch at a certain window size?
This is still very new to me so i really appreciate the help 
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add `geometry` to the command with the values you need:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --command /home/noah/bin/clock --geometry=24x24
```

You can see all options with this command

```
gnome-terminal --help-all
```

Output:

```
Usage:
  gnome-terminal [OPTION?] [-- COMMAND ?]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                      Show help options
  --help-all                      Show all help options
  --help-gtk                      Show GTK+ Options
  --help-terminal                 Show terminal options
  --help-window-options           Show per-window options
  --help-terminal-options         Show per-terminal options

GTK+ Options
  --class=CLASS                   Program class as used by the window manager
  --name=NAME                     Program name as used by the window manager
  --gdk-debug=FLAGS               GDK debugging flags to set
  --gdk-no-debug=FLAGS            GDK debugging flags to unset
  --gtk-module=MODULES            Load additional GTK+ modules
  --g-fatal-warnings              Make all warnings fatal
  --gtk-debug=FLAGS               GTK+ debugging flags to set
  --gtk-no-debug=FLAGS            GTK+ debugging flags to unset

Options to open new windows or terminal tabs; more than one of these may be specified:
  --window                        Open a new window containing a tab with the default profile
  --tab                           Open a new tab in the last-opened window with the default profile

Window options; if used before the first --window or --tab argument, sets the default for all windows:
  --show-menubar                  Turn on the menubar
  --hide-menubar                  Turn off the menubar
  --maximize                      Maximize the window
  --full-screen                   Full-screen the window
  --geometry=GEOMETRY             Set the window size; for example: 80x24, or 80x24+200+200 (COLSxROWS+X+Y)
  --role=ROLE                     Set the window role
  --active                        Set the last specified tab as the active one in its window

Terminal options; if used before the first --window or --tab argument, sets the default for all terminals:
  -e, --command                   Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal
  --profile=PROFILE-NAME          Use the given profile instead of the default profile
  -t, --title=TITLE               Set the initial terminal title
  --working-directory=DIRNAME     Set the working directory
  --wait                          Wait until the child exits
  --fd=FD                         Forward file descriptor
  --zoom=ZOOM                     Set the terminal?s zoom factor (1.0 = normal size)

Application Options:
  --load-config=FILE              Load a terminal configuration file
  --preferences                   Show preferences window
  -p, --print-environment         Print environment variables to interact with the terminal
  -v, --verbose                   Increase diagnostic verbosity
  -q, --quiet                     Suppress output
  --display=DISPLAY               X display to use
```

Comment: I'll leave my answer as an alternate but I'm upvoting yours and think it should be the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks just what i was looking for.  Is there a list of commands you could point me to

Comment: @un_armed_pawn You are welcome. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Select `Edit` and then `Profile Preferences`:

[image: Terminal Edit Profiles.png]

Notice `92` columns and `30` rows. You can adjust these values to make terminal larger or smaller. In my case I have it set exactly 1 row less than needed (as I just discovered whilst answering your question):

[image]

Comment: thanks.  this does work. but i don't want every terminal to then launch at that size (small 35x8) . only the one at startup.  If i use this method i will have to resize every other terminal i use.  I was hoping there is a way to add a size indicator to either the scrip that launches the clock or the file saved in /.config/autostart

Comment: @un_armed_pawn Yes I realized that too late. The other answer is better and I upvoted it.